# How to click on an image and open the link in a new window in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating my portfolio in reactjs and I made thumbnails that you can click on to go to the website that I have created so they can see my work, but it opens in the same window. I would like to click on the thumbnail(image) and for it to open the link(website) in a new window(tab). Any ideas on how to get the `link: "https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/",` to open in a new window? I tried target="_blank" and it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Here is the code for project.js file:

```
import { CodeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import React from "react";
import { projects } from "../data";

export default function Projects() {
return (
    <section id="projects" className="text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 body-font">
        <div className="container px-5 py-10 mx-auto text-center lg:px-40">
            <div className="flex flex-col w-full mb-20">
                <CodeIcon className="mx-auto inline-block w-10 mb-4" />
                <h1 className="sm:text-4xl text-3xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-white">
                    My Past Projects
                </h1>
                {/* <p className="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">
                    Description
                </p> */}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap -m-4">
                {projects.map((project) => (
                    <a
                        href={project.link}
                        key={project.image}
                        className="sm:w-1/2 w-100 p-4">
                        <div className="flex relative">
                            <img
                                alt="gallery"
                                className="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full object-cover object-center"
                                src={project.image}
                            />
                            <div className="px-8 py-10 relative z-10 w-full border-4 border-gray-800 bg-gray-900 opacity-0 hover:opacity-100">
                                <h2 className="tracking-widest text-sm title-font font-medium text-green-400 mb-1">
                                    {project.subtitle}
                                </h2>
                                <h1 className="title-font text-lg font-medium text-white mb-3">
                                    {project.title}
                                </h1>
                                <p className="leading-relaxed">{project.description}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);
}
```

Here is the code for data.js file:

```
export const projects = [
  {
    title: "Siemens Digital Industries Software",
    subtitle: "Wordpress, PHP, HML, CSS and Javascript",
    description:
  "I worked with a development team on this project using a variety of front-end technologies to help build their blogs, podcasts, solid edge and Learning Management System utilizing LearnDash for the education certification site",
image: "./project-1.png",
link: "https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/",
  },
  {
title: "Signature Doors",
subtitle: "Java, MySQL",
description:
  "I worked with a software development team on this project to help build a web application that calculates customer quotes, customer accounts, view notifications, keep track of orders and projects, inventory and CAD/CSR Department. Login: UN:info@talixa.com; PW: password",
image: "./project-2.png",
link: "https://apps.talixa.com/doors/login.faces",
  },
  {
title: "B & D Glass",
subtitle: "Wordpress, Elementor, PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript",
description:
  "I developed this website from start to finish and maintained it using a variety of front-end technologies such as Wordpress, PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript",
image: "./project-3.png",
link: "https://banddglassllc.com/",
  },
  {
title: "Jones Insurance",
subtitle: "Wordpress, Elementor, PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript",
description:
  "I also developed this website from start to finish and maintained it using a variety of front-end technologies such as Wordpress, PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript",
image: "./project-4.png",
link: "https://jonesinsurancewv.com/",
  },
];
```

Comment: Your [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-rain-3ebsx?file=/src/App.js) is working fine in sandbox with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following as the callback for `onClick` for your image / whatever the wrapper element giving the `url`.

Define this function inside your `Projects` function.

```
const openInNewTab = (url) => {
    const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
    if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
}
```

In your image element

```
<img
   alt="gallery"
   className="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full object-cover object-center"
   src={project.image}
   onClick={() => { openInNewTab(project.link) }}
/>
```

**Full code snippet is given below**

```
import { CodeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import React from "react";
import { projects } from "../data";

export default function Projects() {

const openInNewTab = (url) => {
    const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
    if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
}

return (
    <section id="projects" className="text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 body-font">
        <div className="container px-5 py-10 mx-auto text-center lg:px-40">
            <div className="flex flex-col w-full mb-20">
                <CodeIcon className="mx-auto inline-block w-10 mb-4" />
                <h1 className="sm:text-4xl text-3xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-white">
                    My Past Projects
                </h1>
                {/* <p className="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">
                    Description
                </p> */}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap -m-4">
                {projects.map((project) => (
                    <a
                        href={project.link}
                        key={project.image}
                        className="sm:w-1/2 w-100 p-4">
                        <div className="flex relative">
                            <img
                                alt="gallery"
                                className="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full object-cover object-center"
                                src={project.image}
                                onClick={() => { openInNewTab(project.link) }}
                            />
                            <div className="px-8 py-10 relative z-10 w-full border-4 border-gray-800 bg-gray-900 opacity-0 hover:opacity-100">
                                <h2 className="tracking-widest text-sm title-font font-medium text-green-400 mb-1">
                                    {project.subtitle}
                                </h2>
                                <h1 className="title-font text-lg font-medium text-white mb-3">
                                    {project.title}
                                </h1>
                                <p className="leading-relaxed">{project.description}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);
}
```

Comment: @baiy33, check this out!!

Comment: @baiy33, find the full code at the end of the answer.